# SQL Server:Dynamic Join clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables :

TableA

`Id    extId`

TableB

`Id1 ID2 ID3 id4`

Now I want to write a join on tableA with tableB.
Query should first join on `TableA.extid=TableB.Id1`.
If no record found, join should happen on `TableA.extid=tableB.Id2` etc..
What is the best way to achieve this in sql server?

Comment: Does this a _do my job for me_ question? please show us what did you try at  very least.

Comment: Seems like two OUTER JOINs with COALESXE().

Comment: Is there a reason to have four TableA-IDs in your TableB? On first glance this looks like a bad idea.

Comment: I understand this as: "`select * from a join b on a.id = b.id1`. If this brings back an empty result, do `select * from a join b on a.id = b.id2`. If this is empty again, then ...". Is this correct? Are you talking of the query result like I assume? Or are you talking of the result per *row* instead? I.e. if for a *row* in TableA there is no match in TableB for ID1, then try2, etc.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner you are correct in your first assumption.if first join doesnt return result then 2nd join with different id from table b..Right now I am using this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use multiple `left join`s:

```
select coalese(a1.id, a2.id, a3.id, a4.id) as a_id, b.*
from b left join
     a a1
     on b.id1 = a1.extid left join
     a a2
     on b.id2 = a2.extid and a1.extid is null left join
     a a3
     on b.id3 = a3.extid and a2.extid is null left join
     a a4
     on b.id4 = a4.extid and a3.extid is null 
where a1.extid is not null or a2.extid is not null or a3.extid ia not null or a4.extid is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand the task as: join the tables on ID1. If the query brings no result, then join the tables on ID2. Etc. If this is correct then:

You can simply join on all IDs and then keep only the rows joined on the "best" ID with a `TOP` clause:

```
select top(1) with ties *
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.extid in (b.id1, b.id2, b.id3, b.id4)
order by
  case when a.extid = b.id1 then 1
       when a.extid = b.id2 then 2
       when a.extid = b.id3 then 3
       when a.extid = b.id4 then 4
  end;
```

If you rather mean *rows* (i.e. if there is no match for ID1 for a TableA row in TableB, then try ID2, etc.), then you'd use the same technique, but use a window function partitioned by ID instead:

```
select top(1) with ties *
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.extid in (b.id1, b.id2, b.id3, b.id4)
order by 
  row_number() over (
    partition by a.id
    order by 
      case when a.extid = b.id1 then 1
           when a.extid = b.id2 then 2
           when a.extid = b.id3 then 3
           when a.extid = b.id4 then 4
      end);
```

Sample data:

```
TableA

ID   | EXTID
-----+------
100  | 1
200  | 2
300  | 3
400  | 4

TableB

ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4
----+-----+-----+----
2   | 3   |     |
2   | 4   |     |
3   | 4   |     |
3   | 2   | 4   | 1

Result for query #1 (all matches on ID1):

ID  | EXTID | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4
----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----
200 | 2     | 2   | 3   |     |
200 | 2     | 2   | 4   |     |
300 | 3     | 3   | 4   |     |
300 | 3     | 3   | 2   | 4   | 1

Result for query #2 (first matching ID):

ID  | EXTID | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4
----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----
100 | 1     | 3   | 2   | 4   | 1
200 | 2     | 2   | 3   |     |
200 | 2     | 2   | 4   |     |
300 | 3     | 3   | 4   |     |
300 | 3     | 3   | 2   | 4   | 1
400 | 4     | 2   | 4   |     |
400 | 4     | 3   | 4   |     |
```

Answer (score 0):

UNION might be a good option if there are known number of Id1, Id2, Id3, Id4, etc.

```
SELECT ta.Id,
ta.extId,
tb.Id1 AS JoinedID
FROM TableA ta
INNER JOIN TableB tb ON ta.extId = tb.Id1

UNION

SELECT ta.Id,
ta.extId,
tb.Id2 AS JoinedID
FROM TableA ta
INNER JOIN TableB tb ON ta.extId = tb.Id2

UNION

SELECT ta.Id,
ta.extId,
tb.Id3 AS JoinedID
FROM TableA ta
INNER JOIN TableB tb ON ta.extId = tb.Id3

UNION

SELECT ta.Id,
ta.extId,
tb.Id4 AS JoinedID
FROM TableA ta
INNER JOIN TableB tb ON ta.extId = tb.Id4
```